SVG linearGradient not working in Chrome, Edge or Opera
I'm adding svg logos to my portfolio and one has a couple <linearGradient> elements in it.  The logo shows up perfectly in Firefox but in Chrome, Edge and Opera the portions with a linear gradient don't display.  I define the logo as a <symbol> like this
<symbol id="cypress_logo" width="297.863159px" height="120.045601px" viewBox="0 0 297.863159 120.045601">
    <style type="text/css">
      .cy_st0{fill:url(#cypress_x5F_gradient_x5F_03_2_);}
        .cy_st1{fill:var(--cy_color01);}
        .cy_st2{fill:url(#cypress_x5F_gradient_x5F_01_2_);}
        .cy_st3{fill:var(--cy_color02);}
        .cy_st4{fill:url(#cypress_x5F_gradient_x5F_03_3_);}
        .cy_st5{fill:url(#cypress_x5F_gradient_x5F_01_3_);}
    </style>
    <linearGradient id="cypress_x5F_gradient_x5F_03_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="160.038849" y1="182.399033" x2="205.718689" y2="231.221817" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -106 -186.390198)">
      <stop offset="0.0939" style="stop-color:var(--cy_color01); stop-opacity: 1;"/>
      <stop offset="0.9883" style="stop-color:var(--cy_color01); stop-opacity:0"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <path id="cypress_x5F_gradient_x5F_03_1_" class="cy_st0" d="M106.290375,36.263775
      C97.286957,19.007219,79.530205,8.253134,60.272896,8.253134c-6.752567,0-13.505131,1.250476-19.757504,4.001521L37.264156,4.50171
      C44.516914,1.50057,52.269859,0,60.272896,0c22.508545,0,43.01635,12.504749,53.520325,32.262253L106.290375,36.263775z"/>
    
    <path id="cypress_x5F_gradient_x5F_02_1_" class="cy_st1" d="M2.250855,76.028877C0.750285,70.776878,0,65.524887,0,60.0228
      c0-24.509312,15.505889-47.01786,38.514629-56.021282l3.001141,7.752945C21.758265,19.50741,8.253135,38.764725,8.253135,60.0228
      c0,4.751804,0.50019,9.253513,1.750666,13.755222L2.250855,76.028877z"/>
    
    <linearGradient id="cypress_x5F_gradient_x5F_01_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="105.350082" y1="273.759186" x2="192.619492" y2="296.987274" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -106 -186.390198)">
      <stop offset="0.0774" style="stop-color:var(--cy_color01);"/>
      <stop offset="0.7617" style="stop-color:var(--cy_color02);"/>
    </linearGradient>

    <path id="cypress_x5F_gradient_x5F_01_1_" class="cy_st2" d="M66.525269,105.039902l-2.000755,5.0019
      c-0.500191,1.000381-1.250477,1.750664-2.250854,1.750664c-0.750282,0-1.500572,0-2.000759,0
      c-24.009121,0-45.267197-17.006454-50.519192-40.265297L1.500574,73.27784
      c3.00114,13.004936,10.253895,25.009499,20.757885,33.512726c10.75408,8.503227,24.009115,13.255035,37.764343,13.255035l0,0
      c0.750282,0,1.500568,0,2.50095,0c4.251617-0.250092,8.253136-2.751045,9.7537-6.752571l2.751045-6.502464L66.525269,105.039902z"/>
    
    <path id="cypress_x5F_wordmark_1_" class="cy_st3" d="M42.266052,47.518047c4.751804,0,8.753326,2.50095,10.754089,7.002659
      l0.250095,0.250095l8.253132-2.751045l-0.250095-0.500191c-3.251232-7.752945-10.50399-12.504749-19.007221-12.504749
      c-6.002277,0-11.004177,2.000755-15.005699,6.002277s-6.002277,9.003422-6.002277,14.755604s2.000759,10.754082,6.002277,14.755608
      c4.001522,4.001518,9.003422,6.002274,15.005699,6.002274c8.503231,0,15.755989-4.751801,19.007221-12.504745l0.250095-0.500191
      l-8.253132-2.751045l-0.250095,0.250092c-1.750668,4.501709-5.752182,7.002655-10.754082,7.002655
      c-3.501331,0-6.252377-1.250473-8.503231-3.501328s-3.501328-5.251995-3.501328-8.753323s1.250475-6.502472,3.501328-9.003422
      C36.01368,48.768524,38.764725,47.518047,42.266052,47.518047z M142.804245,45.267197
      c-3.751434-4.001522-8.503235-6.002281-14.005325-6.002281s-10.003792,2.000759-13.505127,5.752182v-5.0019h-8.753326v55.020905
      h8.753326V74.778404c3.501335,3.751427,8.003036,5.75219,13.505127,5.75219s10.253891-2.000763,14.005325-6.002281
      c3.751419-4.001518,5.50209-8.753326,5.50209-14.505512S146.555664,49.268715,142.804245,45.267197z M135.801575,68.776123
      c-2.250854,2.250854-5.001892,3.501328-8.503227,3.501328s-6.252373-1.250473-8.503235-3.501328
      c-2.250854-2.250854-3.501335-5.251995-3.501335-8.753323c0-3.501331,1.250481-6.502472,3.501335-9.003422
      c2.250862-2.250854,5.0019-3.501331,8.503235-3.501331s6.252373,1.250477,8.503227,3.501331
      c2.25087,2.250854,3.251236,5.251995,3.251236,9.003422C139.302917,63.524128,138.052444,66.525269,135.801575,68.776123z
       M162.561752,45.017097v-4.751801h-8.753326v39.515007h8.753326V57.521851c0-3.501331,1.500565-6.252377,4.251602-8.253136
      c2.751038-1.750668,6.25238-2.250854,10.253891-1.000378l0.500183,0.250095v-8.503235h0.000015
      C171.815262,38.514629,166.313171,40.515392,162.561752,45.017097z M200.826294,39.515011
      c-5.752197,0-10.754089,2.000759-14.755615,6.002281c-4.001511,3.751423-6.002274,8.753323-6.002274,14.505508
      c0,5.752178,2.000763,10.754078,6.002274,14.755604c4.001526,4.001518,9.003418,6.002281,15.005707,6.002281
      c8.253143,0,15.255783-4.251617,18.757126-11.004181l0.250092-0.500191l-7.502853-3.251236l-0.250092,0.250099
      c-2.250854,4.251617-6.25238,6.752563-11.004181,6.752563c-6.25238,0-11.004181-3.751427-12.254669-9.753704h32.012177v-0.500191
      c0.75029-6.502472-1.000381-12.004562-5.001907-16.506271C212.330658,41.765865,207.078659,39.515011,200.826294,39.515011z
       M189.321899,56.021278c1.50058-5.50209,6.002289-8.753326,11.254288-8.753326c5.502075,0,10.003799,3.501331,11.504364,8.753326
      H189.321899z M244.592911,56.271374c-4.751801-1.000378-9.003418-1.750668-9.003418-5.0019
      c0-2.751045,2.751053-4.501709,6.752563-4.501709c4.501724,0,7.00267,2.000759,7.502853,5.752186v0.500191l8.753326-1.750668
      v-0.500191c-1.250488-7.002659-7.502853-11.254276-16.25618-11.254276c-4.501724,0-8.253143,1.250477-11.254272,3.501328
      c-3.001129,2.250854-4.501724,5.251999-4.501724,8.753326c0,5.251995,3.251251,9.003422,8.753326,10.253895
      c1.500565,0.250095,3.001129,0.500195,4.501724,0.750286c5.502075,1.000378,10.503983,2.000755,10.503983,5.50209
      c0,2.751045-3.251251,4.751801-8.003036,4.751801c-4.751801,0-7.502853-2.000755-8.003036-5.752182V66.77536l-8.753326,1.750671
      v0.500191c1.250488,7.002655,7.502853,11.254265,17.00647,11.254265c4.751816,0,8.753326-1.250473,12.004578-3.501328
      s5.001892-5.251991,5.001892-8.753326C259.348511,59.022419,251.345474,57.521851,244.592911,56.271374z M282.857452,56.271374
      c-4.751831-1.000378-9.003418-1.750668-9.003418-5.0019c0-2.751045,2.751038-4.501709,6.752533-4.501709
      c4.50174,0,7.002686,2.000759,7.502869,5.752186v0.500191l8.753326-1.750668v-0.500191
      c-1.250488-7.002659-7.502869-11.254276-16.256195-11.254276c-4.501709,0-8.253143,1.250477-11.254272,3.501328
      c-3.001129,2.250854-4.501709,5.251999-4.501709,8.753326c0,5.251995,3.251251,9.003422,8.753326,10.253895
      c1.50058,0.250095,3.001129,0.500195,4.501709,0.750286c5.502106,1.000378,10.503998,2.000755,10.503998,5.50209
      c0,2.751045-3.251251,4.751801-8.003052,4.751801s-7.502838-2.000755-8.003021-5.752182V66.77536l-8.753326,1.750671v0.500191
      c1.250488,7.002655,7.502838,11.254265,17.00647,11.254265c4.751801,0,8.753326-1.250473,12.004578-3.501328
      c3.251221-2.250854,5.001892-5.251991,5.001892-8.753326C297.613037,59.022419,289.359894,57.521851,282.857452,56.271374z
       M93.285431,40.265297L81.781067,69.776505L70.026596,40.265297h-9.503605l16.506268,40.265297l-12.004562,28.010635
      l8.253136,1.750671l28.760925-70.026596C102.038757,40.265301,93.285431,40.265301,93.285431,40.265297z"/>
  </symbol>

Then in my HTML I use it like this
<svg viewBox="0 0 297.863159 120.045601" class="techLogo">
    <use href="#cypress_logo" style="--cy_color01: hsl(var(--gray-300), 1); --cy_color02: 
    hsl(var(--gray-500), 1);" />
</svg>

I came across other articles on here where someone was having the same problem however the issues people had revolved around case sensitivity like doing <lineargradient> instead of <linearGradient>.  I exported the SVG from Illustrator and noticed it created a couple extra classes that aren't used so I'm wondering if it did something else strange that prevents it from working.  Can someone shed light on why this is happening?

It's like they moved the definition of the gradient outside of the 's shadow clone, or that they make the href point to the one in the light DOM which actually would make sense when the  is below in the DOM than the gradient. Anyhow, the CSS variable doesn't apply on it as it would in the light DOM. I don't see in the specs that they handle this particular case. It's definitely worth a few bug reports. Be it at Chrome, Firefox, or maybe even the specs.

Ps: looking at the shadow tree they produce, Chrome doesn't move the gradient there, so they definitely do something wrong, still I'd be curious about the resolution of the href in that case.

@Kaiido yeah I wondered about the CSS variables too and tried hardcoding the colors in and they still wouldn't show up.

Oh? Hardcoding the values should work, but even if you define the variables directly on the original linearGradient that should also work

I tried your SVG, but the linear gradient looks great on both Firefox and non-Firefox browsers. Capitalizing or not does not matter to me. Maybe you can add some screenshots for better understanding? And you can check if the code you've provided is enough to reproduce this problem.
